# What is the meaning of "rather one" in the sentences?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "rather one" in the following sentences, (Source: Are coronavirus tests flawed? By James Gallagher )

> There has also been some discussion about whether doctors testing the
>   back of the throat are looking in the wrong place. This is a deep lung
>   infection ***rather one*** in the nose and throat.

Does "This is a deep lung infection rather one in the nose and throat" mean "This is a deep lung infection rather than infection in the nose and throat" ?

Comment: Yes. I think the word *than* has gone missing. "This is a deep lung infection rather *than* one in the nose and throat."

Comment: I agree with @OldBrixtonian, it appears to be a simple typing error.